# How can I pass two Id within URL using getParameters().put

Tags: parameters, global-variables

currently I send one Id in the URL to my other controller but now I have to send another value within the same URl to my other controller , how can I add the second value to this

```
PageReference opptyPage = new PageReference('/apex/PBXOrdering');
       opptyPage.getParameters().put('id', Opportunity.id);
      opptyPage.setRedirect(true);
```

what I wish,

```
PageReference opptyPage = new PageReference('/apex/PBXOrdering');
       opptyPage.getParameters().put('id', Opportunity.id + 'xyz', currenId);
      opptyPage.setRedirect(true);
```

also how do I receive both Id's individual for my two different variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add both to the map:

```
opptyPage.getParameters().put('id', Opportunity.id);
opptyPage.getParameters().put('xyz', currenId);
```

On the page where the data is retrieved from, just read the parameters back using the get method:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParamters().get('id');
ApexPages.currentPage().getParamters().get('xyz');
```

Comment: thank you so much, I have a quick question , what if i have urlId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ;  , can I have both of them in there?

Comment: @bez You can do whatever you want within the context of it being a single string. For example, you could combine them like this: `put('id', Opportunity.Id+';'+currenId);`, but this *may* break certain pages (those with standard controllers). It's better to avoid using 'id'. If you did combine them, you could then split them up later: `.get('id').split(';')`. That's really more complicated than it needs to be. Just use two parameters.